# Xamarin Forms Custom ViewCell, don't add to grid if empty?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've created a Custom Viewcell, where i bind text to a label and then insert it in a grid. However, how do I avoid empty rows, if the text I pass to the Viewcell is empty? This is just some of the code, but is there somekind of binding I am missing if the text is empty?

```
public RouteElementsCustomCell()
{
    Label NameLbl = new Label()
    {
        TextColor = Color.Black,
        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
        FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label))
    };
    NameLbl.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "StopName");

    Grid grid = new Grid()
    {
        Padding = 10,
        RowDefinitions =
        {
            new RowDefinition
            {
                Height = GridLength.Auto
            },
        }
    };
    grid.Children.Add(NameLbl,0,1,0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so this is how I solved this issue with help from @irreal.

> This is probably introducing unneeded complexity to your viewmodel. Consider using a xaml value converter which would convert string to boolean. You would then just bind IsVisible="{Binding StopName, Converter={}}" It is super useful, and would allow you to do lots of things, including control visibility based on string not being null or empty  - @irreal

Added the Label.IsVisibleProperty to the label, then used an IValueConverter, to check if the string was empty, null or whitespace.

**Label**

```
Label NameLbl = new Label()
{
    TextColor = Color.Black,
    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label))
};
NameLbl.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "StopName");
NameLbl.SetBinding(Label.IsVisibleProperty, "StopName",BindingMode.Default,new StringToBoolConverter(), null);
```

**ValueConverter**

```
public class StringToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string valueAsString = value.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueAsString))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably introducing unneeded complexity to your viewmodel. Consider using a xaml value converter which would convert string to boolean. You would then just bind IsVisible="{Binding StopName, Converter={<your custom value converter>}}" It is super useful, and would allow you to do lots of things, including control visibility based on string not being null or empty.

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is add a public property to my object:

```
public bool ShowItem { get{return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(StopName)};}
```

Then bind the IsVisibleProperty to ShowItem

Comment: Not the right solution, because you would have add multiple bools for your object if you have a lot of properties for an object. Therefor the right way to solve it is to use the iValueConverter, to avoid code duplication.

Comment: I disagree - the one bool could check multiple properties of the object and return one result.

Comment: It still sounds like a bad solution to me. Imagine that I have 10 properties I want to show in a listview, but I only want to show properties that are not empty. How will you validate this with 1 bool property?